# How to index a very large graph using Hadoop MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, graph, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a very large graph (100 billions links, 1TB) in the form of a long text file, where each line defines the graph arc.

**ref file**

```
page1, page2
page3, page10
page5, page 1
.
.
.
pageN, pageM
```

where pageN can be any webpage.

To save space I want to convert this graph to an indexed version (with two files).

**index file (node file):**

```
page1, 1
page2, 2
page3, 3
page4, 4
.
.
.
pageN, N
```

**and the arc file (links):**

```
1, 2
3, 10
5, 1
.
.
.
N, M
```

Are there any MapReduce(Hadoop, Pig, etc) algorithms to do this conversion efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

With Pig this is easy. First you'll need to get a list of all the unique pages in your graph. You should be able to get this with `DISTINCT` and possibly `UNION` if there are pages in one column that don't appear in the other. Next, you can use the `RANK` function to assign each page a unique ID. Save that as your first file.

Then, you can use `JOIN` to bring in those IDs to your list of graph edges. Save that as your second file.

If you have any trouble with any of the steps, feel free to post a specific question about that step and we can help you with it.

Comment: Thanks. It looks clear. I wondering what is the complexity of the Pig JOIN function? How much resources do I need to join 100B ref file with 1B index file. I guess there is not way around it. Right?

Comment: The complexity is O(n log n) because MapReduce uses a quicksort/merge join. (If you are referring to the runtime complexity)